# how to get analytics data without login into account

Tags: google-analytics, google-api-js-client

i am currently using gapi-google-analytics to get data from analytics without login credentials

but i am getting nothing in the output of this.getting blank page as a output

my code is given below:

```
    require 'gapi-google-analytics/gapi.class.php';

     $ga = new gapi('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-uq0529xxxxxxxucf1pjlnk45t8nd00gup@developer.gserviceaccount.com','testproject.p12');
 $metrics=array('pageviews');
 $dimensions=array('browser','browserVersion');
 $ga->requestReportData('11111554',$dimensions,$metrics,'-visits');
 //echo"123";exit;
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
 echo '<strong>'.$result.'</strong><br />';
 echo 'Pageviews: ' . $result->getPageviews() . ' ';
 echo 'Visits: ' . $result->getVisits() . '<br />';
}

 echo '<p>Total pageviews: ' . $ga->getPageviews() . ' total visits: ' .     $ga->getVisits() . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use a service account make sure that you go to the Admin page on Google Analytics website and add the service account email address as a user at the Account level.   This will give the service account permission to access your data.

**Update**

Google Analytics data is private data, data that is owned by a user.  In order to access someone's private data you must have there permission.  You can not access Google Analytics data without some form of authentication.

Comment: is there any way to get information without login into the google account?

Comment: In order to access private data, you need to be authenticated.   Service accounts are pre-authenticated by adding the service account email address as a user from the google analytics admin page.   If you don't have access to that then the user will need to grant you access using Oauth2.